# API returns an object but $resource expects array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

Hello I have my API that returns an array or an object

`/models (array of models)`

`/models/1 (object)`

```
function ModelsFactory($resource) {

    return $resource('http://api.mysite.com/models/:id');
}
```

the angular js error is pretty clear

```
Error: $resource:badcfg
Response does not match configured parameter
```

but I need a config that works for both arrays or objects right? how to fix this? thank you!

Comment: Easy, use `Models.query()` for the array response and `Models.get({id: 1})` for the object

Comment: exactly. just found it. thank you!!